# Passing a function of a class as argument to call it on a list of classes

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

I'm trying to call functions of a list of classes of the same type using a function. I want this, because I have to loop over several objects and do the same operation on each of them, and I have several differing functions running such a `for` loop.

Given this:

```
def make_timeSeries(symbol):
    return pandas.DataFrame(symbol) # Pseudo-code; But the return value is a pd.DataFrame Object nonetheless.

Class TimeSeries:
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.series = make_timeSeries(symbol)

    def get_y_of_day(self, day, _type):
    # Returns a y value for a given X (date) value from a timeline.
        if isinstance(day, str):
            day = funcs.convert_str_to_datetime(day)
        return self.series[(self.series['Date'] >= day) &
                           (self.series['Type'] ==
                            _type)].head(1)['Value'].values[0]

Class Market:
    def __init__(self, symbols):
        self.instruments = {}
        for symbol in symbols:
            self.instruments[symbol] = TimeSeries(make_timeSeries(symbol))

    def _market_day_apply_funcs(self, func, func_list=None, *args):
    # calls a given class function of TimeSeries for each TimeSeries stored in self.instruments
        ys = []
        for symbol in self.instruments:
            ys.append(self.instruments[symbol].func(args))
        if func_list is None:
            return ys
        else:
            return func_list(ys)

    def market_ys_of_day(self, day, _type):
    # Masking function, returns a list of all instruments at the given X (Date) value.
        return self._market_day_apply_funcs(get_y_of_day, day, _type)
```

I'm calling it then as follows:

```
print(market.market_ys_of_day('2016-2-1', 'vola'))
```

This, however raises a `NameError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/markets.py", line 73, in <module>
    print(market.market_ys_of_day('2016-2-1', 'vola'))
  File "/markets.py", line 38, in market_ys_of_day
    return self._market_day_apply_funcs(get_y_of_day, day, _type)
NameError: name 'get_y_of_day' is not defined
```

I'm assuming the way to resolve this Error would be to pass the entirety of `self.instruments[symbol].func`, but that would defeat the purpose of the function itself, which is to not have a repeating `for` loop in each `market_day_*` function.

Anyone know a solution for this?

**Edit**
It may be of interest to state that my IDe highlights the `func` argument as not used in the function's scope. Extra credit if anyone can explain that bit as well.

Comment: Try `TimeSeries.get_y_of_day`

Comment: @cdarke I believe that won't work, because that method uses instance variables of the class. I believe you first would need to create a TimeSeries object and pass that.

Comment: Where do you actually generate an instance of `market`?

Comment: Yea, it doesn't - still a `NameError`.

Comment: in my main loop, with `market = Market(symbols)`.

Comment: About your edit, you're just not using `func` anywhere from what I can tell. `self.instruments[symbol].func` should maybe be `self.instruments[symbol][func]` if that's your intention.

Comment: Nah, it isn't. `func` is the function of `self.instruments[symbol]` I want to call.

Comment: @j4ck: Okay, then the warning is there because you're not using `func` anywhere :)

Comment: Well, cheers @damd, I've gotten that far as well ;D I suppose that means you can't pass a function like this at all then, without passing the class it belongs to?

Comment: @j4ck: You can, but your code is honestly a bit hard to follow for me, so I don't really know what's going on. You can take a look at `getattr`, but again, I don't really know what you're doing, so maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: I get that it might not be crystal clear what I'm doing - I've tried to reduce the clutter before posting it, but it's from a pretty big piece of code. I've added 2-3 comments to maybe clear it up a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I can see:

```
ys.append(self.instruments[symbol].func(args))
```

should be:

```
ys.append(func(args))
```

and

```
return self._market_day_apply_funcs(get_y_of_day, day, _type)
```

should be:

```
return self._market_day_apply_funcs(TimeSeries.get_y_of_day, day, _type)
```

Comment: Yes, which is essentially what I suggested in my post, correct? i.e. pass `self.instruments[symbol].func` whereas `self.instruments[symbol]` is equivalent to your `TimeSeries` above. So I have to pass the instance along with it as an argument for the `func` to work.

Comment: The problem was that the `func` you are passing into the method is not the same as the `func` you are using in the `append` (which is why IDLE complains).  The `func` argument is a complete reference to a specific function.